# how to retrieve the RDD dependencies from pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

How can I retrieve an RDD's dependencies from PySpark?

Scala has the [`dependencies()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#dependencies()) method:

```
public final scala.collection.Seq<Dependency<?>> dependencies()
```

I couldn't see an equivalent method in the PySpark [`RDD` class](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD). Is there some other way that I can retrieve the RDD dependencies in PySpark?

I have seen the `toDebugString` method. But this is really only suitable for interactive spark sessions.

Answer (score 1):

[pyspark api](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html) has the information that you require. `toDebugString()` is the method you are looking for

> toDebugString(self)
>   A description of this RDD and its recursive dependencies for debugging.

Comment: Upvoted, however, I had seen this method.  I’ve updated the question to reflect that.